# How do I customize the display of username field of default User Model in Django ModelForm without extending User Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have a default `User` Model, with which I have connected a `ModelForm`. In the `ModelForm`, I am accessing the `username` field of the default `User` Model. It works fine as usual, it shows the `username`(s) of the users. But I don't want it to just show username, instead I want to show the custom content of each user. I want to show `first_name`, `last_name` and `username` of the user in the following format:
`{first_name last_name - (username)}`

Current display of the `username` filed:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
#
#
#
```

Desired display of the `username field:

```
John Doe - (user1)
Doni Marquart - (user2)
Geoff Roberts - (user3)
Alice Woods - (user4)
#
#
#
```

Does anyone know how can I accomplish it without extending the default User Model? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in you'r templates :

```
{% for user in user_list %}
    {{ user.first_name }}
    {{ user.last_name }}
<!--  ....    --/>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that's fine, but I am using a `forms.ModelForm` not `forms.Form`, and `forms.ModelForm` shows the `username` filed in the form of a dropdown list, as it shows in the Django Admin Panel. So, I want that dropdown list of users in the way that I explain in **Desired** section.